# How to remove a manual archetype from eclipse

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I have created this for spring framework

Archetype Group Id: co.ntier
Archetype Artifact Id: spring-mvc-archetype
Archetype Version: 1.0.2
Repository URL: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/co.ntier/spring-mvc-archetype/1.0.2

And I am getting the following error using this archetype:

```
Unable to create project from archetype [co.ntier:spring-mvc-archetype:1.0.2 -> ]
The defined artifact is not an archetype
```

How do I remove a manual archetype from Eclipse?

Comment: Have you published that archetype to the maven repository and want it to be removed from there or do you just want it to not be listed in eclipse?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to remove only from the list in eclipse.I have not published this archetype. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows under c:\users{user}.m2 there is a file named archetype-catalog.xml. Open it remove the element for the archetype you want to delete and restart Eclipse.

Comment: @Donovan I confirm this DOES NOT work on Windows for Eclipse 2019-09 even after multiple restarts of Eclipse and the entire system. The archetypes from previous snapshot builds still remain in the Nexus Indexer Catalog. Is there a way to purge the Nexus Indexer Catalog?

Comment: @Donovan I found a workaround by creating a new Local Catalog with the archetype-catalog.xml in the .m2 directory and disabling the Nexus Indexer. Works sweet now.

Comment: It's under `C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository`.

Answer (score 1):

In mac its in /Users/
You can see the m2 folder inside that you can find archetype-catalog.xml